# Convert MKAnnotation array to set

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have a situation where I have map annotations as [MKAnnotation] array in swift. Now I need to convert this into a set for some operation. How can I do this in swift? Basically I need to add only the non existent annotations on the map while updating the map view.

Comment: This gives me an error: "Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred"

Comment: How is your array declared?

Comment: It is basically a map view. So I am taking self.mapView.annotations

Comment: Since that will be an `NSArray` you will need to tell swift your specific element type; `let annotationSet = Set<MKAnnotation>(annotationArray)`, but really you should have your own array of your specific annotation objects rather than relying on the map views `annotations` property

Comment: I tried the above but this gives me an error: " Type 'MKAnnotation' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable' "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178251/discussion-between-paulw11-and-nikhil-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

You can find out if an annotation exists on the map by using `mapView.view(for:)` [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51017631/7488171):

```
    if (self.mapView.view(for: annotation) != nil) {
        print("pin already on mapview")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*"Basically I need to add only the non existent annotations on the map while updating the map view."*

We first need to define what makes two annotations equal (in your scenario). Once that is clear you an override the `isEqual` method. You can then add annotations to a `Set`.

Here is an example :

```
class MyAnnotation : NSObject,MKAnnotation{
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?

    convenience init(coord : CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String) {
        self.init()
        self.coordinate = coord
        self.title = title
    }

    private override init() {
        self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    }

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let annot = object as? MyAnnotation{
            // Add your defintion of equality here. i.e what determines if two Annotations are equal.
            return annot.coordinate.latitude == coordinate.latitude && annot.coordinate.longitude == coordinate.longitude && annot.title == title
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

In the code above two instances of `MyAnnotation` are considered equal when you they have the same coordinates and the same title.

```
let ann1 = MyAnnotation(coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 20.0, longitude: 30.0), title: "Annot A")
let ann2 = MyAnnotation(coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0), title: "Annot B")
let ann3 = MyAnnotation(coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 20.0, longitude: 30.0), title: "Annot A")

var annSet = Set<MyAnnotation>()
annSet.insert(ann1)
annSet.insert(ann2)
annSet.insert(ann3)

print(annSet.count)  // Output : 2 (ann1 & ann3 are equal)
```